# if stament for atrribute with no value

Tags: node.js, pug, vue.js

I have two `<input>` elements. They are quite similar.
So I try define their in one place.

For attributes with different value I can wrote something like:

```
input(type="text", placeholder="{{(address.$index == 0)? ph1 : ph2}}",  .....)
```

But I have no idea how to wrote if/else logic when attribute have no value.
For example i need `autofocus` attribute in one `<input>` element based on `address.$index` value

**Update**:
My *.jade file

```
#my-input
   .my-input
       input(type="text", 
             autofocus="{{(condition == 0)? true : false}}", 
             placeholder="{{(condition == 0)? 'focused onLoad' : 'not focused'}}")
```

My actual result is:

```
<div class="my-input">
   <input type="text" autofocus="true" placeholder="focused onLoad">
</div>
......
<div class="my-input">
   <input type="text" autofocus="false" placeholder="not focused">
</div>
```

But I need:

```
<div class="my-input">
   <input type="text" autofocus placeholder="focused onLoad">
</div>
......
<div class="my-input">
   <input type="text" placeholder="not focused">
</div>
```

Comment: Not a good approach trying to access the input using $index from outside the loop. Please provide more code. Including where your v-for is, and the data property used for it.

Comment: Actually i didn't see `v-for` in this my source code file.
But I will try add more code for explanation my problem.

Comment: Disregard my comment. There is a tag for vue.js here and I thought that you were using it.

Comment: I use it, but after code simplification (for "simple example" purpose) vue.js code gone away.
I think my solution is in fields of `v-focus`,`v-focus-auto` or something similar. But i can't understand how to cook it right.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code, It works:

```
    div.my-input 
            input(type="text", autofocus="",placeholder="focused onLoad")

div.my-input
            input(type="text",placeholder="not focused")
```

```
<div class="my-input"> 
  <input type="text" autofocus="" placeholder="focused onLoad"/>
</div>
<div class="my-input">
  <input type="text" placeholder="not focused"/>
</div>
```

Like you can see here the demo [link](http://codepen.io/Rebbit/pen/PzoXyr)